# ActiveSync library for Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, activesync

I am writing on a cross-platform BB application that needs to connect to Exchange servers and download mails using ActiveSync.
Is there any library or API available for BB?
Please suggest me how can I perform this task in Blackberry?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KXML](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/) parser written in java for ActiveSync wbxml or [JavaScript](https://github.com/mozsquib/jswbxml) library for ActiveSync implementation in JavaScript